# How to build a .exe program from the Anaconda environment (Python 3.7)

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, exe, pyinstaller

How can I build a .exe program from my Anaconda environment to get a standalone application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Comment: But that question is not specific enough for Windows (EXE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an environment with all packages needed for your program and run `python your_script.py` or `pyinstaller --onefile <your_script_name>.py` if you want a one-file .exe only.